# carousel-layout-android library first load issue

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview, android-viewgroup

I am using "https://code.google.com/p/carousel-layout-android/" in my android application. When it load first time images in carousel are of different sizes, when I scroll all the images till last item, then its images size becomes ok, like center image is big in size and left and right image is bit small in size.

Comment: try https://github.com/davidschreiber/FancyCoverFlow

Comment: I want behavior exactly like "carousel-layout-android". Fancy coverflow is different. One more thing "carousel-layout-android" working correctly on android version 2+ but not working correctly on 4+.

Comment: These are some of the libraries giving weired behaviour in different versions. Try to go for some alternate!! There are some more are available which could be modified to that extent as you want.

Comment: Could you please refer me any library that would give behavior like my requirement